# start java Android Activity from Qt/QML and then go back

Tags: android, qt, android-activity, java-native-interface, qml

I have a QT activity that launches a android activity using JNI to connect with facebook.
This is working properly but I need that my app after getting facebook permissions, go back to qml in QT

This is how I call Java activity from QT

```
void FacebookAndroid::startAndroidFacebook() {
QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org.qtproject.example.MainActivity",
                                          "startFacebookActivity",
                                          "()V");

}
```

This is the java activity that I call- I implemented a button to go Back to Qt activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ....
  static public void startFacebookActivity() {
  String msgTag = "FACEBOOK_APP";
  try {
      Log.v(msgTag, "starting activity");
      Activity mother = QtNative.activity();
      Log.v(msgTag, mother.toString());
      Log.v(msgTag, MainActivity.class.getName());
      Intent intent = new Intent(mother, MainActivity.class);
      mother.startActivity(intent);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(msgTag, e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

        public void goBack(View v){
         Log.d(QtApplication.QtTAG, "######### BACK BTN PRESSED");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
         //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);

         intent.setClassName(this, QtActivity.class.getName());
         startActivity(intent);
         //navigateUpTo(intent);
    }

}
```

As you can see I tried setting all kind of flags for the intent to correctly go back 
to the previous QML screen , but nothing works.
When is pressed back it should go back to my main QML screen.

So, can anybody help?? I believe this should be a common scenario: start java Android Activity screens from withinQt/QML and then go back.

Comment: You have to fire your intent from an activity that [_extends_ `QtActivity`](http://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-7/). You may want to have two activities in this case, your `MainActivity` which should extend `QtActivity`, and a `FacebookLoginActivity` that is started by `MainActivity`. Make sure to declare `FacebookLoginActivity` in your manifest file.

Comment: What is `QtNative` here? How to get `Activity` here?